# Codeigniter - Displaying 2 different Data from 2 Different Model Functions in 1 View

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter, and i'm stuck with this problem.

I have 2 functions in my model, namely :

```
public function getAdminCred()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username,password,owner FROM login");
            return $query->result();
        }

    public function countUsers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

Which i will be sending to my Controller:

```
public function Dashboard()
{
    $adm['USERS'] = $this->user_model->getAdminCred();
    $rowcount['COUT'] = $this->user_model->countUsers();
    var_dump($rowcount);

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('pages/dashboard', $rowcount);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

But everytime i display the both of $adm['USERS'] and $rowcount['COUT'] at the same time, only one of them works, and the other sends an error "Unidentified Variable".

```
<div class="huge"><?php echo $COUT; ?></div>
<div class="huge"><?php foreach($USERS as $usr); echo *INSERT ECHO TABLES HERE* ?></div>
```

Is there a way to display both of them? Or is Codeigniter only allowing 1 data to be displayed at an instance?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, when i var_dump the other one, it displays the correct Data, but PHP gives out an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array_for_view = array(
    'somevar1' => $this->model->getsomething1();
    'somevar2' => $this->model->getsomething2();
);
```

OR

```
$array_for_view['somevar1'] = $this->model->getsomething1();
$array_for_view['somevar2'] = $this->model->getsomething2();
```

and then pass to your view:

```
$this->load->view('someview', $array_for_view);
```

Of course you can merge the arrays as you are doing in your answer but the above methods are preferred and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

A bit unrelated but why do you fetch all users just to get the user count?

You could just do:

```
$this->db->count_all_results('users')
```

which would look something like this in SQL:
`SELECT count(*) FROM users`

That would speed up the database side of things a lot when you start getting more users.

on topic to solve your problem, I would do:

```
$this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', [
    'admin' => $adm,
    'row_count' => $rowcount
]);
```

Comment: or better `$this->db->count_all_results('users')`

Answer (score 0):

So i feel so dumb xD

I found an answer for the problem.

Instead of doing this:

```
$this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $adm, $rowcount);
```

Do this instead :

```
$this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $adm + $rowcount);
```

aaaand it solved my problem. Thanks anyways :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use two array variables? Use one array to store your view related data instead.

```
$adm['USERS'] = $this->user_model->getAdminCred();
$adm['COUNT'] = $this->user_model->countUsers();

$this->load->view('pages/dashboard', $adm);
```